# Distance between multiple vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vector, euclidean-distance

I have two sets of three-dimensional unit-vectors that I would like to get a measure of how similar they are. My current method is to manually calculate the euclidean norm of their difference.

An example (without considering unit-vectors) would look like

```py
import numpy as np

N = 4000
a = np.random.rand(3,N)
b = np.random.rand(3,N)

dist = np.sum((a-b)**2,axis=0)
dist = np.sum(dist)/len(dist)
```

Are there better ways to do this; i.e. a numpy function or a measure I haven't thought of?

Comment: What you're currently doing is just getting the average pairwise distance for an effectively arbitrary ordering of vectors. This could give wildly varying results depending on how the input happens to be ordered, so I would recommend a different approach (e.g. distance between bounding box centers, distance between median/mean points, etc.)

Comment: Those sound like better options. In my case all the vectors are unit-vectors. With that consideration I don't think bounding box centers would work, what do you think?

Comment: Do you mean they're all within the unit cube? Not sure what the final application looks like, but the code above would put them within a unit cube rather than making them unit vectors.

Comment: The above example was just meant to illustrate the shape of my vectors (3,N). I mean unit-vector as in magnitude of 1.

Comment: In that case I would just take the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) of the mean vectors of the sets. The fact that they're already unit vectors would make cosine similarity a bit faster to implement too.

Comment: Put an answer with example code down below. Let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate Euclidean distance in numpy you can use

```
numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)
```

Also there are other types of distances, measuring other types of similarities. SciPy has a lot of them implemented and described in docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use distance in scipy package.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

distance.euclidean(a, b)
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, this solution only works for 1-D vectors.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html

Comment: @fibbi not sure if that make sense. If the two vectors `a` and `b` are only 1 D, then their Euccledian distance is simply `abs(a - b)`. No need for a library. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the question comments, this should be more appropriate for what you're trying to do:

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np

N = 10
a = np.random.rand(3, N)
b = np.random.rand(3, N)

mean_a = np.mean(a, axis=1)
mean_b = np.mean(b, axis=1)

similarity = spatial.distance.cosine(mean_a, mean_b)
```

Values closer to 1 are more similar, values closer to 0 are less similar.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think this would work for my purpose. vector `a[4]` could point in a different direction than `a[5]` which is very plausible. I would like to compare `a[4]` to `b[4]` etc. and then have a similarity across all observations.